# xgboost does't train data in parallel mode with the dask

Tags: python

I start my dask cluster mode,and my code is like this

```
   import dask.dataframe as dd
   import time
   import dask
   from dask.distributed import Client, progress
   data= dd.read_csv('/data2/data_dask/detail_1219_V1_v2.csv',encoding='gbk')

   y = data.target
   x = data.drop(['target'],axis=1)
   data_train, data_test = x.random_split([0.7, 0.3], 
                                     random_state=1234)
   labels_train, labels_test = y.random_split([0.7, 0.3], 
                                                random_state=1234)
   from dask_ml.xgboost import XGBClassifier

   est = XGBClassifier()
   est.fit(data_train, labels_train)
```

but I look into dask's status window,the result shows like this:
[image: Status Window]

train part seem to be done by only one worker.

Maybe there is something wrong with my code,Could I get any help